# In upgrading to Django 1.8, why do I get the AttributeError 'ManyToManyRel' object has no attribute 'rel'?

Tags: python, django, upgrade, models, django-errors

I'm going through and checking the various pages in our project, and the great majority appear to be working fine after the upgrade.  However, when I try to view a particular entry in the admin, I get this error.  On viewing the stack trace, everything is being done internally within Django's admin code, so there is no place in my own code that I can go to debug.  This would suggest either that there is something wrong with the Django admin or that there is some release note I missed that is necessary to make this work properly.  Any ideas?  The actual error is happening here:

site-packages/django/contrib/admin/helpers.py in contents, line 206

```
if isinstance(f.rel, ManyToManyRel) and value is not None:
    result_repr = ", ".join(map(six.text_type, value.all()))
else:
    result_repr = display_for_field(value, f)
```

Obviously, I could go into Django and hack around, but I shouldn't have to do this on a new installation.  Any help on pinpointing the issue would be much appreciated.  I'm just staring t the screen at this point.

Comment: Please post the model and model admin that are causing the error. The full traceback might help as well.

Answer (score 2):

Was responding to Alasdair's comment and got to playing with our admin code, and I was able to narrow it down to the method call that was causing the error.

We have a `Lead` model that relates to our `Company` model via a ManyToManyField (i.e. one lead can be for one or more companies).  The field that relates `Lead` to `Company` has a `related_name` of "leads".

```
class Company(models.Model):
    ...

class Lead(models.Model):
    companies = models.ManyToManyField(Company, blank=True, related_name='leads')
    ...
```

The `CompanyAdmin`, looks like the following:

```
class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    readonly_fields = 'leads',
    ...
    def leads(self, obj):
        ...
```

So what appears to have been happening was, when we were trying to access the `leads` method from `CompanyAdmin`, Django was instead trying to access the company's `Lead` objects via the related name -- the ManyToManyField that was throwing the error.  I resolved the conflict by changing the method name in the admin to "my_leads".

Looks like something was changed somewhere between 1.8 and the final version of 1.6 that has opened the door to potential conflict between related names and admin methods.  The solution, make sure there is no overlap in naming, and things should work fine.

Comment: Please keep follow ups in the comments, or edit the original question. Answers are for answers, not for adding detail.

Comment: My initial assessment was a bit mysterious, but further investigation has led to a better answer.  Updated.